# Postgres EXPLAIN and where to put indexes

Tags: postgresql, indexing, explain

I'm trying to make some sense from postgres `EXPLAIN` output. I want to learn where to put indexes in different scenarios.

One example is:

```
EXPLAIN for: SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "user_sessions" ON "user_sessions"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "user_sessions"."token" = $1 AND (user_sessions.expires_at > '2017-09-29 08:56:26.388291') [["token", "foo"]]
```

Gives me:

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=0.30..16.35 rows=1 width=192)
   ->  Index Scan using index_user_sessions_on_token on user_sessions  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=4)
         Index Cond: ((token)::text = 'foo'::text)
         Filter: (expires_at > '2017-09-29 08:56:26.388291'::timestamp without time zone)
   ->  Index Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.15..8.17 rows=1 width=192)
         Index Cond: (id = user_sessions.user_id)
```

Would a single index `[user_id, token, expires_at]` be "more" appropriate than two indexes with `user_id` and `[token, expires_at]`?

Comment: Note: your query will yield duplicates if more than one matching user_sessions rows are found. (I suggest using an EXISTS() construct)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could improve by dropping the index on `token` and replacing it with one on `(token, expires_at)`. Then the whole condition on `user_sessions` could be used as index condition, which would save unnecessary index reads and heap checks and make the query more efficient.

To see if that really has much effect, run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` in both cases. If there are a lot of rows removed by the filter and more blocks touched, the query will be slower.

An index on `user_sessions (user_id)` won't help at all, because this condition is never searched: First, PostgreSQL find all rows in `user_session` based on the conditions on `token` and `expires_at`, then it finds all matching rows in `users`.

Comment: Awesome response, last paragraph is spot on. Now I have a better understanding how it works. Thank you!